# Riemann Sum - region of a function in the interval [a, b]

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like some assistance in constructing the Riemann integral of a function over the interval [a, b] as illustrated in the image.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What hve you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try yourself? Better than  `tikz` package try with `pgfplots`.

Comment: How to create this graph in LaTeX?

Comment: I tried the TikZ package, but I'm having trouble making these markings on the axes and also the gradient in the region and the function!

Comment: @FernandoBerrig Feel free to show us what you've got so far.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: People are much more inclined to answer (and much less inclined to close or downvote) questions which include a complete small example with code you've tried, even if the closest you can get isn't very close at all. `pgfplots` is certainly better if you want to plot graphs generally, I think. For one thing, there are more examples around, I think, than of tikz' graph stuff. But if you only want a look-alike, tikz might be enough.

Comment: Do you have a function or is it just some curve? Do you really need that fading of the function? You will have to use `path fading`. For the rectangles, if you construct them as one path you can use one fading with a left color and a right color. How would you determine the height of those rectangles? That's the most non-TikZ problem you've got here.

Answer (score 2):

A quick-and-dirty approach via the `intersections` library and some random curve.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, calc, fadings, intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={a=2; b=5; dx=(b-a)/10;},
  x=+5mm, y=+5mm,
  curvy/.style={thick, blue!50!green},
]
\path (right:a) coordinate (b-0)  node[below] {\strut$a$}
      (right:b) coordinate (b-10) node[below] {\strut$b$};

\draw[curvy, path fading=west] (1,1) to[out=70, in=210] (a, 2.8) coordinate (i-0);
\draw[curvy, name path=curve]  (i-0) to[out=210+180, in=175] (b, 1.4) coordinate (i-10);
\draw[curvy, path fading=east] (i-10) to[out=175+180, in=250] (6.5, 3.5);

\path[overlay, name path=vert] foreach \i in {1, ..., 9}{
  (right:a+dx*\i) coordinate (b-\i) -- +(up:5)};
\scoped[on background layer]\fill[
  name intersections={of=curve and vert, name=i},
  left color=blue!50!green, right color=blue!25!green]
  foreach \i[count=\j from 1] in {0, ..., 9}{
    let \p{L} = (i-\i), \p{R} = (i-\j), \n0={min(\y{L},\y{R})} in
    ([xshift=+.5\pgflinewidth]b-\i)
    rectangle +([xshift=+-\pgflinewidth] dx,\n0)
  };

\draw[step=1] (-1,-2pt) grid (8,2pt) node[below] at (right:8) {\strut$x$}
              (-2pt,-1) grid (2pt,5) node[left]  at (up:5)    {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu's default PDF viewer doesn't like `path fading` while TeXstudio's internal does. I've used the former for taking the screenshot.

Comment: Incredible, thank you very much! It looks really good!

Comment: You've been incredible, it looks excellent, speechless to thank you, thank you very much!